# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket (using Plesk)

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean, plesk

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`

I'm using Plesk as server admin. I think this error has to do with Plesk because before using it had installed Vespa Admin and everything ran smoothly.

I'm using DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that mysql service is up and running at least. Try to restart it. Check mysql log if it can't be started.

Comment: Mysql is running. `mysql start/running, process 13153`

Answer (score 0):

```
service mysql stop
rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
service mysql start
```